# MySQL: Inserting row with default values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with something like 100 columns and now I would like to insert a row with some columns equal to some values and default values for all other columns. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
insert into tablename (col1, col22, col33) values (1, 2, 3)
```

The columns not listed in the column list will be assigned to their default values.

You can also do:

```
insert into tablename values (1, default, 3, default, 5, ..., 100)
```

But nothing I'd do with 100 columns. Too easy to make mistakes.

Comment: I did it but the columns are empty, not filled with default values

Comment: @bpesunny Obviously - these columns doesn't have default values set in table definition.

Comment: @Andy You are probably right, they are not in the table definition. Is it possible somehow to fill them (with random values or so)?

Comment: If you don't specify a value at INSERT, you will either get the default value (if such exists), or NULL.